# fetch_assoc() returning only first row

Tags: php

Im fairly new to OOP way of coding and I want to fetch a record of users in my DB

This is my code below:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'goldpalace');

class User {

    public $connect;
    public function get_users() {
        $sql = "SELECT * from users";
        $result = $this->connect->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
                return $data;
            }
        }
    }
}

$obj = new User();
$obj->connect = $con;
$user_data = $obj->get_users();
foreach ($user_data as $value) {
    echo $value['name']."<br>";
}
```

I have a lot of records in my DB but it only returns the first row.

Comment: FetchAll() use if have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you return the value of `$data` *immediately* after you retrieve one row. `return` will return that value and stop execution of that method. You need to return that value *after* you are done retrieving your values.

```
class User {

    public $connect;
    public function get_users() {
        $sql = "SELECT * from users";
        $result = $this->connect->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        $data = [];
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

FYI, you can use [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) here to make this a bit simpler:

```
class User {

    public $connect;
    public function get_users() {
        $sql = "SELECT * from users";
        $result = $this->connect->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        $data = [];
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For you return in the first cycle in while

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[] = $row;
   return $data;
}
```

just move the return out of while loop

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
```